# Is there an advantage to excluding special characters from passwords?

Tags: security, passwords, entropy

Recently I ran in to two strange error messages when setting a password, one on the [Chipolte mobile ordering app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chipotle-ordering/id327228455?mt=8) and the other on a financial services portal.  In both cases I was prevented from setting a password because it contained non-alphanumeric characters.  The financial services site also imposed a maximum length that I thought was rather odd (no passwords greater than 8 characters, [seems extremely short sighted](http://xkcd.com/936/)).  I was wondering if there is any security justification for a password policy that prevents certain characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *security* justification. More characters allowed is always better, for security, because it increases the number of potential combinations.

The only "justifications" are either shortsightedness or some form of storage or transmission issue (which would be solvable through proper encoding). Maybe they don't know how to do parameterized queries and are worried about users trying to use passwords for injection attacks? Who knows. They should be salting and hashing anyway, at a minimum, which really takes care of most storage concerns at least.

They may be trying to make sure users don't write down their passwords and instead choose ones that are "easy to remember," but this is counter productive: users who were already going to write down passwords still will, and brute forcing everyone else's passwords just became that much easier.

If they are also trying to be case-insensitive for passwords and that is somehow a reason for this choice, I would be even more worried, on a number of levels.

Answer (score 1):

This type of restriction is often because legacy systems on the back end cannot handle non-Alphanumeric characters, or have defined a short maximum field width for the password character in the database.

Sometimes it can be very challenging to make changes to legacy apps (not that it is hard per se, but it is often not an IT priority).

I have specifically seen it with SAP integrations.

Comment: Hard to imagine Chipotle having legacy systems.

Comment: @Alan: Who knows?  Maybe they use something like SAP on the back end.  Maybe V1 of their App was written by some offshore site that just didn't do a good job.  I have seen both.

Comment: There might be something to your SAP idea.  Chipotle and SAP both appeared at a sustainability brands conference [earlier this year](http://parkhowell.com/tag/chipotle)

Answer (score 0):

It's may be because when checking if passwords are correct after you make one it converts all the characters to their ASCII values and the special characters aren't included in the programming range. as for only 8 chars when they store your password and username info on their servers it reduces the space it takes up, true its not very much but it could become surmountable eventually.

Comment: So the advantages are space savings and matching efficiency? (at the cost of actual security of course)

Comment: if i make my password XxCruStYxX no one will guess that, but i see your point

Comment: Wow, turns out Stack Overflow has a password [hiding feature](http://www.bash.org/?244321), on my browser all I see is "if i make my password `**********` no one will guess that, but i see your point" :)

Comment: On the question of special characters, pretty much all of the "special characters" used in passwords _are_ perfectly valid in ASCII. And on the subject of length, if a site is storing your actual password, then they might decide to limit its length for space-saving reasons. But if they're storing your actual password, then they (and you, as a user) have bigger problems :P